# How do I bind grid on clicking on specific tab in jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery tabs for displaying gridviews. Project requirements is that when user clicks on a tab gridview should be refreshed.My code is

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#divtab1">Inbox</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#divtab2">Outbox</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#divtab3">Archive</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="divtab1" runat="server" style="padding: 25px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to bind gridview on clicking on a specific tab ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code for Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#tabs {
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            background: #ffffff;
            color: #222222;
        }
        div#tabs ul {
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            background: #cccccc;
            color: #222222;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        div#tabs ul li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            margin: 1px .2em 0 0;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
            padding: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            background: #e6e6e6;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #555555;
        }
        a {
            float: left;
            padding: .5em 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #555555;
        }
        .active {
            margin-bottom: -1px;            
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            background: #ffffff;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #212121;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#divtab1" data-key="Title">Inbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#divtab2" data-key="Director">Outbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#divtab3" data-key="ReleaseDate">Archive</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="divtab1" style="padding: 25px;"></div>
                    <div id="divtab2" style="padding: 25px;"></div>
                    <div id="divtab3" style="padding: 25px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tabRef = 'div#tabs ul li a'
        var tabContRef = 'div#tabs div.container';
        var tabClass = 'active';
        $(tabRef).click(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass(tabClass)) {
                var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');//Current container id
                var thisDataKey = $(this).attr('data-key');//data key
                var responseContainerRef = tabContRef + ' div' + thisHref;//Getting selector of current conatiner
                $(tabContRef + ' >div').hide();//Hiding all tab container
                $(responseContainerRef).fadeIn(200);//Showing current container
                $(tabRef).removeClass(tabClass);
                $(this).addClass(tabClass);
                var currentResponseHtml = $.trim($(responseContainerRef).html());
                if (currentResponseHtml == "" || currentResponseHtml == "Synchronization Error!!")
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "RepaterDataInHTML.aspx?SortBy=" + thisDataKey,//adding query string value
                        type: "GET", cache: "false",
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $(responseContainerRef).html('Loading Please Wait...');
                        }, success: function (htmlResponse) {
                            $(responseContainerRef).html(htmlResponse);
                        }, error: function () {
                            $(responseContainerRef).html('Synchronization Error!!');
                        }
                    });
            }
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and use this code for binding repeater or gridview I'm using repeater here

aspx page code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RepaterDataInHTML.aspx.cs" Inherits="RepaterDataInHTML" %>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="_gridView" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <asp:repeater runat="server" id="_repDB">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <tr><th scope="col">Title</th><th scope="col">Director</th><th scope="col">Genre</th><th scope="col">RunTime</th><th scope="col">ReleaseDate</th></tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr><td><%#Eval("Title")%></td><td><%#Eval("Director")%></td><td><%#Eval("Genre")%></td><td><%#Eval("RunTime")%></td><td><%#Eval("ReleaseDatestr")%></td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
</table>
```

and code behind code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class RepaterDataInHTML : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Movie> DBrep = new List<Movie>();
        DBrep = new DataBaseInFormOfList().GetMovies();
        List<Movie> DBsort = new List<Movie>();
        if (Request.QueryString["SortBy"] != null)
        {
            string SortBy = Request.QueryString["SortBy"].ToString();
            if (SortBy == "Title")
            {
                DBsort = DBrep.OrderBy(o => o.Title).ToList();
            }
            else if (SortBy == "Director")
            {
                DBsort = DBrep.OrderBy(o => o.Director).ToList();
            }
            else if (SortBy == "Genre")
            {
                DBsort = DBrep.OrderBy(o => o.Genre).ToList();
            }
            else if (SortBy == "RunTime")
            {
                DBsort = DBrep.OrderBy(o => o.RunTime).ToList();
            }
            else if (SortBy == "ReleaseDate")
            {
                DBsort = DBrep.OrderBy(o => o.ReleaseDate).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                DBsort = DBrep;
            }
            _repDB.DataSource = DBsort;
            _repDB.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            //Response.Write("No Data Found");
        }
    }
}
public class DataBaseInFormOfList
{
    public List<Movie> GetMovies()
    {
        return new List<Movie> {
                new Movie { Title="Shrek", Director="Andrew Adamson", Genre=0,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("16-05-2001"), RunTime=89 },
                 new Movie { Title="Fletch", Director="Michael Ritchie", Genre=0,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("31-05-1985"), RunTime=96 },
                new Movie { Title="Casablanca", Director="Michael Curtiz", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("01-01-1942"), RunTime=102 },
                new Movie { Title="Batman", Director="Tim Burton", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("23-03-1989"), RunTime=126 },
                new Movie { Title="Dances with Wolves",
                   Director="Kevin Costner", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("21-11-1990"), RunTime=180 },
                new Movie { Title="Dirty Dancing", Director="Emile Ardolino", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("21-08-1987"), RunTime=100 },
                new Movie { Title="The Parent Trap", Director="Nancy Meyers", Genre=0,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("29-07-1998"), RunTime=127 },
                new Movie { Title="Ransom", Director="Ron Howard", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("08-11-1996"), RunTime=121 },
                new Movie { Title="Ocean's Eleven",
                   Director="Steven Soderbergh", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("07-12-2001"), RunTime=116 },
                new Movie { Title="Steel Magnolias", Director="Herbert Ross", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("15-11-1989"), RunTime=117 },
                new Movie { Title="Mystic Pizza", Director="Donald Petrie", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("21-10-1988"), RunTime=104 },
                new Movie { Title="Pretty Woman", Director="Garry Marshall", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("23-03-1990"), RunTime=119 },
                new Movie { Title="Interview with the Vampire",
                   Director="Neil Jordan", Genre=1,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("11-11-1994"), RunTime=123 },
                new Movie { Title="Top Gun", Director="Tony Scott", Genre=2,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("16-05-1986"), RunTime=110 },
                new Movie { Title="Mission Impossible",
                   Director="Brian De Palma", Genre=2,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("22-05-1996"), RunTime=110 },
                new Movie { Title="The Godfather", Director="Francis Ford Coppola",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("24-03-1972"), RunTime=175 },
                new Movie { Title="Carlito's Way", Director="Brian De Palma",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("10-11-1993"), RunTime=144 },
                new Movie { Title="Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves",
                   Director="Kevin Reynolds",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("14-06-1991"), RunTime=143 },
                new Movie { Title="The Haunted", Director="Robert Mandel",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("06-05-1991"), RunTime=100 },
                new Movie { Title="Old School", Director="Todd Phillips",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("21-02-2003"), RunTime=91 },
                new Movie { Title="Anchorman: The Legend of Ron Burgundy",
                   Director="Adam McKay", Genre=0,
                   ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("09-07-2004"), RunTime=94 },
                new Movie { Title="Bruce Almighty", Director="Tom Shadyac",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("23-05-2003"), RunTime=101 },
                new Movie { Title="Ace Ventura: Pet Detective", Director="Tom Shadyac",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("04-02-1994"), RunTime=86 },
                new Movie { Title="Goonies", Director="Richard Donner",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("07-06-1985"), RunTime=114 },
                new Movie { Title="Sixteen Candles", Director="John Hughes",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("04-05-1984"), RunTime=93 },
                new Movie { Title="The Breakfast Club", Director="John Hughes",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("15-02-1985"), RunTime=97 },
                new Movie { Title="Pretty in Pink", Director="Howard Deutch",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("28-02-1986"), RunTime=96 },
                new Movie { Title="Weird Science", Director="John Hughes",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("02-08-1985"), RunTime=94 },
                new Movie { Title="Breakfast at Tiffany's", Director="Blake Edwards",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("05-10-1961"), RunTime=115 },
                 new Movie { Title="The Graduate", Director="Mike Nichols",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("02-04-1968"), RunTime=105 },
                new Movie { Title="Dazed and Confused", Director="Richard Linklater",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("24-09-1993"), RunTime=103 },
                new Movie { Title="Arthur", Director="Steve Gordon",
                   Genre=1, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("25-09-1981"), RunTime=97 },
                new Movie { Title="Monty Python and the Holy Grail",
                   Director="Terry Gilliam",
                   Genre=0, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("10-05-1975"), RunTime=91 },
                new Movie { Title="Dirty Harry", Director="Don Siegel",
                   Genre=2, ReleaseDate=DateTime.Parse("23-12-1971"), RunTime=102 }
            };
    }
}
public class Movie
{
    private string _title = string.Empty;
    private string _director = string.Empty;
    private int _genre = 0;
    private int _runtime = 0;
    private DateTime _releaseDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    public string Title { get { return _title; } set { _title = value; } }
    public string Director { get { return _director; } set { _director = value; } }
    public int Genre { get { return _genre; } set { _genre = value; } }
    public int RunTime { get { return _runtime; } set { _runtime = value; } }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get { return _releaseDate; } set { _releaseDate = value; } }
    public string ReleaseDatestr { get { return _releaseDate.ToShortDateString(); } }
}
public class Methods
{
    //public string GetPagination(
}
```